# Copying the data of a child class of a parent to another class with same parent

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

This is a tricky answer to find using google since there are many similar questions but different.

Basically the idea is that, I have `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` where they both inherit `ProjectBase`. They parse the data differently but other that each having his own members they both update also the members from `ProjectBase`.

So when we `projecta->Parse()` we want to copy the `ProjectBase` content and use it inside `projectb->Build()`.
Also, those classes have many more member of virtual, unique and shared ptrs.

```cpp
class ProjectBase
{
protected:
    int data;

public:
    virtual void Parse() = 0;
    virtual Zip Build() = 0;
}

class ProjectA : public ProjectBase
{
    void Parse()
    {
        data = 2;
    }
    
    Zip Build()
    {

    }
}

class ProjectB : public ProjectBase
{
    void Parse()
    {
        data = 3;
    }

    Zip Build()
    {
        
    }
}


// I need to copy the content of the ProjectBase (or here it will be int data) from projecta to projectb
std::unique_ptr<ProjectA> projecta = std::make_unique<ProjectA>();
projecta->Parse();

std::unique_ptr<ProjectB> projectb = std::make_unique<ProjectB>();
// ???
// I need to use the data = 2 inside projectb->Build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/501250) is actually what you want. If you upcast the target object reference then the implicit `ProjectBase` copy-assignment operator will do what you want.

```
static_cast<ProjectBase &>(*projectb) = *projecta;
```

This will assign *only* the inherited data members of `ProjectBase` from `*projecta` to `*projectb`.